# Why doesn't Rubymine recognize my namespaced inherited controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubymine

I have a namespace called `backend` and the following controller `application_controller.rb`:

```
class Backend::ApplicationController < ApplicationController
end
```

Now I inherit this controller from my user controller:

```
class Backend::UserController < Backend::ApplicationController
  def index
    @users = User.all
  end

  ...
end
```

For the inheritance of the application controller Rubymine shows me the following error:

[image: Expected: ; or end of line]

This code is fine for the ruby interpreter. How can I teach this to Rubymine?

I'm on RubyMine 2018.2.3 and using Ruby 2.5.1p57.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Are both *Backend* controllers located at `app/controllers/backend/*.rb`?

Comment: Yes, both of them are in `app/controllers/backend/`

Comment: I've just installed RubyMine 2018.2.3 and i can confirm this problem. It occurs only if you type in the text. I think its a bug and should be reported to https://youtrack.jetbrains.com. As a workaround: try to remove the text _Backend::ApplicationController_ and paste it back again. That seems to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing that you should try the proper "longhand" way of actually opening the module.

These two approaches are not actually equivalent:

```
class Backend::ApplicationController < ApplicationController
end

module Backend
  class ApplicationController < ::ApplicationController
  end
end
```

As the later actually properly sets the module nesting to work as expected:

```
module Backend
  # this class will inherit from Backend::ApplicationController
  # and not ::ApplicationController
  class UserController < ApplicationController
  end
end
```

In general the "short-cut" definition (`class Foo::Bar`) of "namespaced" classes should be avoided as it invites problems with constant lookup.

Comment: I do realise that Rails generates classes with `class Foo::Bar` but thats because the code templates would become much more complicated if they had to deal with module nesting properly - not because its a good practice.

Comment: Using the "longhand" way is also recommended by the [Ruby style guide](https://github.com/rubocop-hq/ruby-style-guide#namespace-definition).

Comment: Thank you for this information. I've learned something to improve my style of writing Ruby. It also works just fine with RubyMine, but the other way of writing it should also work. As pointed out by @lual it seems to be a bug. I've reported it to JetBrains.